# PHP Or (||) Operator Issue

Tags: php, operator-keyword

Facing an issue regarding or (double-pipe) operator in PHP.

```
<?php
    
    
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$token = fetchToken();
fetchActiveCompanies($token);

function fetchActiveCompanies($token){
    
    //GET THE COMPANIES
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    $vars = 'Id, Member_Status__c, Name';
    $query = 'https://xxx.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v50.0/query?q=SELECT ' . $vars . ' FROM Account';
    
    $query = str_replace (' ', '%20', $query);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $query,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $token
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    
    $obj = json_decode($response);
    $records = $obj->records;
    
    $activeRecords = array();
    foreach($records as $record){
    
        $id = $record->Id;
        $status = $record->Member_Status__c;
        var_dump($status);
        
        if (($status == "Active") || ($status == "Pending Resignation")){
        //if ($status == 'Active'){
            
            $object = array();
            $object['name'] = $record->Name;
            $activeRecords[] = $object;
            
        }
    }
    
    echo("record is " . json_encode($activeRecords));
    return json_encode($activeRecords);

}

function fetchToken(){
    
    //returns token string; 
}
?>
```

getting an `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function` on if statement line within foreach loop. Tried with `or`  and with and without bracketed cases. Single if-case works fine for both comparisons, just not with the double-pipe. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT OUTPUT MESSAGE:

```
var dump: string(6) "Active" string(6) "Active" string(9) "Cancelled"
error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function  () [if line]
```

The eror occurs on a comparison of $status var against string. In this case, I only care about 'Active' and 'Pending Resignation' status. It's as if it's looking for an else statement to cover the 'Cancelled' status, as their should be a fourth 'Active' record after, and it breaks on third loop iteration.

Comment: Have you tried removing the parentheses?

Comment: Seems like you are calling a function inside the condition that is not in the scope. Not an issue with condition but with the call inside the condition if you have any functions there.

Comment: @christian yep, as in if ($status == "Active" || $status == "Pending Resignation")

Comment: This code snippet does not invoke a function. Which line number did the error occur?

Comment: and nothing?,mmm

Comment: @MaartenDev the error is called on the if statement, I've added contextual code, wondering if the $status object is causing the issue, as if not being compared as a string literal

Comment: @christian no unfortunately no change...

Comment: @JohnnyRockex Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Also include the full complete error message you get, for the MCVE you have posted.

Comment: Did you check the line number of the error? This foreach does not contain any function invocations

Comment: @minimal more context added. The commented out if statement works, and a literal comparison to either Active or Pending Resignation work. It just hates the logical or.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex The code you have posted is still not complete. Also the error message is not complete. Please [edit] your question to include a MCVE and the full complete error message. For testing purposes, add a `var_dump($status);` before the `if()` statement to see the content of the `$status` variable.

Comment: @Progman updated with more code.

Comment: The only way I was able to reproduce this is by using U+2800 instead of a regular space character, it's silly but are you sure you are not using a invalid space character? https://3v4l.org/eL3U8

Comment: @mrbm you got it, it was a space issue! FFS. If you post as answer I'll approve now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you sorted it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I was able to reproduce this is by using U+2800 instead of a regular space character, it's silly but are you sure you are not using a invalid space character?

https://3v4l.org/eL3U8